# How to move images up or down in Microsoft Word 2013 with up and down arrows?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I try to find a way to move image to a different position in Word. The reason is that some of the printscreens I pasted in the Word-document, have to change places. For example: I pasted as such: A, B, D, C. I need to change position of C and D, whether by moving C up, or D down. So the result is A, B, C, D.

With the mouse one can click and drag it somewhere else. But I want to be able to do it by keyboard only, or by mouseclicking on it, and then do the location change with the keyboard. For example click on it with mouse, then press CTRL and up/down/right/left arrows untill the image (or cursor) is on the right location.

Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this, and whether it even is possible?

How to move images up or down in Microsoft Word 2013 with up and down arrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word defaults image arrangements to `In line with text`, which does not allow the image to be moved freely. To change it,

1. Select the images you want to move (you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
   left click to select multiple).
2. Go to the `Format` tab, `Arrange` group and use the `Wrap Text` drop
   down to select `Square` (*FYI: the images may move*).

   [image]
3. Deselect the grouped images by clicking off them (otherwise they
   will move in unison).

You can now select the individual images and move them with the arrow keys.

Comment: thanks. is there any way to make the have bigger steps when pressing the arrow? PS: the Ctrl + left click to select multiple does not work.

Comment: You may want to post that question on its own. Asking clarification questions is OK, but separate questions in comments is not allowed. Sorry. I don't know why Ctrl + click doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'll post a new question for that second part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can move pictures with arrows, but I don't think you can change their order.

A solution could be just to cut it (CTRL+X) then paste it (CTRL+V) to the new location.

So moving the image without mouse (rearranging from A B D C to A B C D):

- select image D
- press CTRL+X
- navigate to the desired location (DOWN ARROW)
- press CTRL+V

Comment: please tell me how to move pictures with arrows then.

Answer (score 0):

To move a picture with arrow keys, select the picture and set “Wrap Text” to “Square” as shown in this picture:

[image: this picture]